# Extracting a specific part from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swifty-json

Hello I am trying to extract only the id value from a JSON.  However if I

```
print(response!["id"])
```

result = "not created" is outputted. reponse is already in JSON format.
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Update 1

```
[

    {
        "user" : {
          "last_name" : "test",
          "email" : "test@test.com",

        },
        "id" : 902,
        "scale" : 7,
        "created_at" : "2018-02-24 06:45:33",
      },
  {
        "user" : {
          "last_name" : "test",
          "email" : "test@test.com",

        },
        "id" : 903,
        "scale" : 7,
        "created_at" : "2018-02-24 06:45:33",
      },
  {
        "user" : {
          "last_name" : "test",
          "email" : "test@test.com",

        },
        "id" : 904,
        "scale" : 7,
        "created_at" : "2018-02-24 06:45:33",
      },
]
```

Comment: this is your full json content?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you for your comment. There are connected. I updated the question

Comment: if this whole response is stored in `response`, then you can not access the `id` like that because the `response` is an array.

Comment: you have an array of objects in your response so, you need to know which object you want to be accessed and then you be able to access to id, with something like this using `for objc in response { debugPrint(objc["id"]) }`should print all your ids

Comment: @hardikparmar Thank you.. what would be the best method to access  id for each []?

Comment: @hardikparmar is right. You need to get a "user" object at the specific index and then you can access `id`. I also recommend you to read my article on parsing of JSON values. (http://kelindev.blogspot.com.by/2018/01/safer-parsing-with-jsonserialization-in.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to access the id of any object from the array of response will be:

```
let id = response[index]["id"]
// Here index is the index of the object you want to access.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to extract ids from this JSON array. You can do this using

```
response.map({ $0["id"]})
```

Which will give you another array containing only ids